# Android- Removing text from canvas drawn by drawText() method

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

As a part of my project, I am creating a basic drawing application. I am using Canvas and Bitmap to draw lines, shapes and text. Now I am implementing the Undo functionality. I implemented it using following method.

Undo Function

```
public void onClickUndo() {
    if (paths.size() > 0) {
        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

`onDraw()` Method

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, drawPaint);

    for (Path p: paths) {
        int curColor = colorsMap.get(p);
        drawPaint.setColor(curColor);
        canvas.drawPath(p, drawPaint);
    }
}
```

where `paths` is list to hold paths and `colorsMap` is map used to hold path along with its colour. Line and other shapes are drawn by using `path.addCircle()`, `path.lineTo()` functions so that the paths can be added to *paths* list.

I am writing text using `drawText()` method. So I can't add it to the *paths* list.

My question is that is there any method to draw text as path or convert text to path so I can add it to the `paths` list?
or any alternative method to undo the text written?

Comment: If you want to be able to undo a text draw like you are a path draw, you should rethink your implementation a little bit. Rather than keeping a list of paths, it's probably going to be easier to keep a list of drawing actions. That is, create some sort of class `DrawAction`, for example, that holds the type of draw, and the relevant information for each, be it a `Path` object, a `String` for text, etc. Then your undo would work similarly to how you have it now, and you could easily add more draw types if desired; e.g., ovals, rectangles, bitmaps, etc.

Comment: Thanks.. I will try..